# Any open source alternatives for JGo?

Tags: java, ide, graph

I came across JGo Java library.

I need something similar but for free and open source. Does anyone has any suggestions ? 
[Any non-Microsoft programming language libraries too will do]

Comment: Removed qt tag, nothing to do with qt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you describe your requirement, afaik, [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) is a good match as compared to JGO.

Comment: I am trying to build a tool for model-based-design where user will drag drop blocks, join them using connectors and then some code will be generated based on those blocks.

Comment: BTW is JGraph free and open source?

Comment: Did you click on the link? The title of the webpage is "JGraph - The Java Open Source Graph Drawing Component"

Comment: I happened to land on a Jgraph site that says "Purchase" so I was deceived. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at

http://argouml.tigris.org/

You can probably reuse parts of it.

Comment: Yes this was very uselful. I am looking at ArgoUML in the reuse point.